# flask 'hello world' not working

Tags: python, flask, python-3.5

I copy pasted the flask's 'hello world' app from their website and am trying to run it. I get an error message in Chrome saying

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Here is the 'hello world' app straight from flasks website

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

What I have tried:

-temporarily disabling Avast!

-disabling windows firewall

-ensuring that the flask module is installed

This was working a couple days ago actually...

Comment: *This was working a couple days ago actually*. Yes, the code works. The error you see is *not produced by Flask*.

Comment: Yeah I know the code is fine, its worked for thousands of newbies before me :). I am wondering what could be preventing it from doing its thing.

Comment: So what are URL are you using in your browser? You'll probably see the *exact same error* when you are **not** running the Flask script. Something else is running there, and it is not working.

Comment: Is there any sort of error message produced in the console in which you run hello.py?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why but when I change

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(port=4996)
```

it starts working. No idea why the default port is throwing an error. Oh well.

Comment: That's because, as I already stated on your question, there is a **different** server running on the other port.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your right, I am new to this and didn't really understand your comment. But your right, even after changing to 4996, 5000 has an error. Thanks!

Comment: This also can happen if you shut the previous process incorrectly while working with flask on 5000, and it is ghosting and taking up the port.

Answer (score 4):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World'


if __name__ == '__name__':
    app.run()

app.run(port=5000)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows machines you can use the command in cmd:

```
set FLASK_APP=python_file.py
flask run
```

Answer (score 1):

Some *other* process is running on port 5000. It may be you still have an old Flask process running, with broken code. Or a different web server altogether is running on that port. Shut down that process, or run on a different port.

You can switch to using a different port with the `port` argument to `app.run()`:

```
app.run(port=8080)
```

If you can't figure out what process is still bound to port 5000, use the Windows Resource Monitor or run `netstat -a -b` from a command line. See [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to copy the route generated through your flask program in cmd by pressing ctrl+c which quits your running flask program . i was also doing the same.just try to type the route generated by your flask program on your browser . it will definitely resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where your python file store is, use cmd and then go on your file store directory, then

```
set FLASK_APP=filename.py
```

After this your flask run cmd will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(__name__) # creating app
   @app.route('/', methods['GET']) #routing it to the home page
   def home(): #function
       return "hello world"
   app.run(port=5000, debug=true) #function call by the app
```

Add port and use methods whatever your need is USE GET in your case and try to remove your cache and run the this code it will definitely work.