# Flask Hello World Program Not working 404 Not Found Error

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get started with Flask, and I get 404 Not Found error for the hello world program.

The program I use:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index.html')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World'

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost')
```

then I run

```
$export FLASK_APP = minimal.py
$flask run
```

Which returns:

```
* Serving Flask app "minimal"
* Forcing debug mode on
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN 127-804-808
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I visit http://localhost:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000, I get:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

And my host file looks like this:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Any idea whats wrong? Thank you

Comment: Your code works for me. My only thought is that `FLASK_APP` is wrong

Comment: What did you do to run the code?

Comment: Solved it with using the following command:   app.run(debug=True, port=4996), I think something was wrong with the default port 5000.

Comment: Where I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818713/flask-hello-world-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can remove the error 404 not found in following ways:
1: You should write command netstat -a -b to check which port is not free or busy doing something or
2: write in your code app.run(port=4996) instead of app.run() which by default choose port no. 50000.