# How do I run my Flask app if nothing happens when i run it through powershell?

Tags: python, flask

I have just started learning about Flask. I installed it on a virtual env.

My app.py file looks like this.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when i run python app.py in powershell nothing happens and it does nothing. I checked that the python is installed and flask is also installed.

Comment: This is hard to answer without inspecting your computer. Try running `flask run` in powershell, and wait for a few minutes till it says its running on address:port.

Comment: I tried running
`set FLASK_APP=app.py`
flask run 
`
it showed and error saying
`
Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'FLASK_APP=app:name' to specify one.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give you an answer because we do not have access to your computer.

- There may be files or programs interfering with your application.
- I would recommend reading [this blog post about running a Flask application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application).
- Alternatively, you could debug your program using Visual Studio Code or another IDE.
- Try finding the port your program is running on and see if you are viewing that port. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818713/flask-hello-world-not-working) similar question for help. For example, try using `app.run(port=4996)`.

Comment: I tried running
`app.run(port=4996)`
still does not work. 
Could not find the solution in the links either.

Comment: A debugged using Visual Code and it ran fine. Now when I am running normally it is creating the route successfully. Thank you.